# Why can't I change the margin of my paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, margin, new-operator

For some context, I am brand new to programming and only about two hours in to an HTML/CSS tutorial, so I don't know many elements, properties etc. beyond what you see in my code here. Forgive me if my terminology is inaccurate, but hopefully this makes sense.

I am doing an exercise at the end of a particular lesson trying to match a design, and trying to eliminate the margin (or blank space) between my first paragraph line and my second paragraph line. As you can see, I've tried changing the margin, line-height, and padding to zero (anything I could think of) but the gap remains.

In the solution code for this exercise, I see the teacher chose to change the bottom margin targeting all paragraphs instead of the specific paragraph classes to make this happen. I would like to understand why that would work, but targeting the specific paragraph classes is not affecting the margin. I assume I will understand this later, but I hesitate to move on until I do.

**My code**

```
<style>
p {
  font-family: arial;
}
.price {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.currency {
  margin-left: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.change {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 0;
}
.after-hours {
  color: gray;
}
.after-hours-change {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<p class="price">1,049.61<span class="currency">USD</span></p>

<p class="change">+18.05 (1.75%) today</p>

<p class="after-hours">After hours 1,048.00 
  
<span class="after-hours-change">-1.61 (0.15%)</span></p>
```

[**Picture of my result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIXbU.png)

**The teacher's solution code**

```
<style>
  p {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .price {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .currency {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  }

  .change {
    color: rgb(24, 128, 56);
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }

  .after-hours {
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  }

  .after-hours-change {
    color: rgb(235, 39, 39);
  }
</style>

<p class="price">
  1,049.61 <span class="currency">USD</span>
</p>

<p class="change">
  +18.05 (1.75%) today
</p>

<p class="after-hours">
  After hours 1,048.00
  <span class="after-hours-change">-1.61 (0.15%)</span>
</p>
```

[**Picture of his result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxVOG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `margin-bottom: 5px;` is not set by you to the `.price`.
Paragraph is a block element, so it adds up a `margin` below, but the `font-size` also counts in -- as I can see.

```css
p {
  font-family: arial;
}

.price {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.currency {
  margin-left: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.change {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.after-hours {
  color: gray;
}

.after-hours-change {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">1,049.61<span class="currency">USD</span></p>

<p class="change">+18.05 (1.75%) today</p>

<p class="after-hours">After hours 1,048.00<span class="after-hours-change">-1.61 (0.15%)</span></p>
```

Comment: Double thanks for the edit

Comment: You're very welcome. You can tweak around with the values. Try out the code inspector (F12) to change the values on the fly, and see directly how the positions are set as you change them.